# How to create a list from another list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python and i was stuck with this. I need to create a list of lists that is
formed from this list `c`: `['asdf','bbnm','rtyu','qwer']`.

I need to create something like this:

`b`: `[['a','s','d','f'],['b','b','n','m'],['r','t','y','u'],['q','w','e','r']]`

I tried using a `for`-loop, but it is not working out. I don't know what mistake I am making.

Comment: Show us what you mean with "I tried", and what you mean "it is not working out". It's hard to tell what your mistake is otherwise.

Comment: That said, `[list(s) for s in c]` should work. `list(x)` converts any *sequence* into a list of its elements, and a `str` is a sequence of its characters. The surrounding stuff is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Why do you need this? You can iterate over a string just as well as a list—what is it that strictly requires a `list`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
>>> c = ['asdf','bbnm','rtyu','qwer']
>>> 
>>> b = [list(s) for s in c]
>>> b
[['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'b', 'n', 'm'], ['r', 't', 'y', 'u'], ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']]
```

Notice that calling `list()` with a string argument returns a list containing the characters of that string:

```
>>> list('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

What we're doing above is applying this to every element of the list via the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Use map function.

```
>>> a= ['asdf','bbnm','rtyu','qwer']
>>> map(list ,a )
[['a', 's', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'b', 'n', 'm'], ['r', 't', 'y', 'u'], ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something that's easier to understand:

```
b = []
for x in c:
    list(x).append(b)
```